# Looking for an open source PDF Framework for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, page-curl

My customer wants a pdf reader which has a page curl effect. Also, he wants it to be zoomable as well. I tried using the `UIPageViewController` but it doesn't support zooming (as far as I know). I also tried using both `UIScrollViewController` and `UIPageViewController` by switching between these 2, but it's not so smooth.

Does anyone know any free framework that meets my requirements?
I don't want any content searching, highlighting or anything, just the reader and thumbnail view.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pdf-reader-core

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pdfreportkit

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. I use vfr at the moment but it doesn't have the curling effect. Will look into pdfreportkit.

Comment: PDF reader core in cocoa controls is good, have used it before.